# Android Studio 3.1.3 Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Good morning.

I am going to develop Android on my company.

I downloaded Android Studio 3.1 and created a new blank project
I get an error.

Gradle download will cause an unconditional error.

I referenced a lot of Google stuff, but I could not solve it.

Help.

1. build.gradle(root)

> buildscript {
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     google()
>     jcenter()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
> } 
>
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>     }
> ```
>
> }

2. build.gradle(project)

> ```
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+' 
> }
> ```

3. gradle.wrapper.properties

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

4. HTTP Proxy Setting

   - Automatic proxy settings check
5. Gradle Sync Exception

   - Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: in HTTP Proxy Setting can you connect to any website on its test connection?

Comment: Can you post exact logs or lines of errors you got in the message view in android studio?

Comment: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" This shows your Internet connection is not good. It cant download required libs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Check Offline work -> press ok` then `sync project`

Answer (score -1):

Got this error log after checked "offline mode" option:
No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta03 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project